# Agile Methodology on College projects?

Tags: agile

I was developing an E-commerce web application using .Net framework for a school project. I have developed each module of these web app like sign in , signup , homepage etc and tested it before moving to the next module. Is this considered as a practice for Agile methodology?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! This question is about engineering practices like TDD, not about project management. As such, it is off-topic here, but may be on topic on Programmers SE.

Comment: I think this is a project management question rather than being about programming. They are trying to understand if by creating one piece of functionality at a time they are working in an agile way.

Answer (score 1):

Agile is an approach rather than a methodology. When following the agile approach we favour interaction (i.e. talking) over process, working software over documentation and responding to change over following a plan.

Developing a web application by building it one piece of functionality at a time is a common agile practice. Typically it would also involve releasing the software as you go along.

So in your case it would be to:

- Build the web application so that users can sign-in and release it.
- Add the ability to sign-up to the web application and then release it again with the enhanced functionality.
- Add a detailed homepage and then again release it.

...and so on.

By using this approach you are favouring having a working product over having comprehensive documentation (such as a detailed specification document). You are also able to respond to change, as by releasing frequently you can easily adapt your web application to changing requirements.

To answer your question, you are taking some steps towards an agile approach. Remember that the important aspects are that you do frequent releases and that you can easily accept changes to requirements.